# How to pass DropDownList SelectedItem into the EntityDataSource Select Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, entitydatasource

I am trying to pass the selected value of ddlCity dropdownlist into the EntityDataSource2 CommandText where "WHERE p.city = @city" but I get the following error:

> WhereParameters cannot be specified unless AutoGenerateWhere==true or Where is specified.

```
<tr id="SearchDropDown">     
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=medicaldb2Entities" 
    DefaultContainerName="medicaldb2Entities" EnableFlattening="False" 
    EntitySetName="Medicals" Select="it.[medicalName], it.[city], it.[Region]">
</asp:EntityDataSource>    
<td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
onselectedindexchanged="ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged"
    DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" DataTextField="city" 
    DataValueField="city">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
</tr>
</table>         

<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource2">
<LayoutTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>    
                    <td>
                        City
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("city") %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            Not Found...
        </EmptyDataTemplate>

</asp:ListView>

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource2" runat="server" 
    CommandText="SELECT p.MedicalID, p.medicalName, p.city, p.Region, p.description, p.Image,     p.adress
          FROM Medicals AS p WHERE p.city = @city"
          AutoGenerateWhereClause="False"
    ConnectionString="name=medicaldb2Entities" 
    DefaultContainerName="medicaldb2Entities">

 <WhereParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCity" DbType="String" 
      DefaultValue="2500" Name="city" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
    ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
  </WhereParameters>
 </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can look at this tutorial [Tutorial: Entity Data Source Control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/18/tutorial-entity-data-source-control.aspx). I believe you will get your answer.

Comment: thanks it looks like a helpful tutorial, I have to read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<asp:EntityDataSource
....
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="costLimit" DbType="Int32" 
          DefaultValue="2500" Name="ordercost" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
        ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
      </WhereParameters>
.....
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Comment: I have tried it, I have changed it as ControlID="ddlCity" and Name="City". Then I have written the query again as p.city = @City but it doesn't work either

Comment: I suppose that you have syntaxe error in your code. You can read Msdn for the syntaxe or post your code

Comment: I add somme properties to he WhereParameters

Comment: since you showed me the right approach I mark your answer as correct but the complete version I have posted below

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct version in order to pass the dropdownlist selectedvalue in the Select attribute of EntityDataSource.

```
    <tr id="SearchDropDown">     
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=medicaldb2Entities" 
    DefaultContainerName="medicaldb2Entities" EnableFlattening="False" 
    EntitySetName="Medicals" Select="it.[medicalName], it.[city], it.[Region]">
</asp:EntityDataSource>    
<td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
onselectedindexchanged="ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged"
    DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" DataTextField="city" 
    DataValueField="city">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
</tr>
</table>



<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource2">

<LayoutTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        City
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("city") %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            not found...
        </EmptyDataTemplate>

</asp:ListView>

 <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource2" runat="server" 
 ConnectionString="name=medicaldb2Entities" 
    DefaultContainerName="medicaldb2Entities" 
EntitySetName="Medicals" 
   Select= "it.[MedicalID], it.[medicalName], it.[city], it.[Region], it.[description], it.[Image], it.[adress]"
    Where = "it.[city] = @city">

    <WhereParameters> 
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCity" DbType="String" 
      DefaultValue="2500" Name="city" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
    ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
  </WhereParameters>

</asp:EntityDataSource>
```