# ASP.Net - DropDownList used in EditItemTemplate in DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, detailsview, edititemtemplate

I have a problem with *DetailsView*. I need to use *DropDownList* for update values in databaze. These values I've got in a different table. I use an ObjectDataSource and it works properly. My problem is how to use the DropDownList when I cannot bind the *SelectedValue* in the designer because it's missing. I found many advices like

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditPermissions" runat="server" DataSource='<%#getPermissions() %>' SelectedValue='<%# Bind("PermissionID") %>'/>
```

But as I wrote the SelectedValue property is not allowed in designer. I'm looking for another way to *SelectedValue='<%# Bind("PermissionID") %>'* because I wanna use DropDownList SelectedValue property as parametr for the ObjectDataSource UpdateMethod.

My update method:

```
    public static void UpdateUser(int UserId, string UserName, int PermissionID)
    {
        using (DC_databazeDataContext db = new DC_databazeDataContext())
        {
            if (!db.DatabaseExists())
                throw new Exception("Databáze neexistuje nebo se k ní nedá připojit!");

            var users = db.USERs.Where(u => u.USER_ID == UserId);

            if (users.Count() == 0) return;

            USER aktU = users.First();

            aktU.USER_NAME_A = UserName;
            aktU.OPRAVNENI_ID = PermissionID;

            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Here is my DetailsVeiw:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="ODS_UzivatelDetail" DataKeyNames="UserId">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserId" HeaderText="UserId" SortExpression="UserId" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PermissionID" SortExpression="PermissionID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditPermissions" runat="server" DataSource='<%# getPermissions() %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lPermissions" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PermissionID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

DB tables:

**Users**

- USER_ID - *int*
- PERMISSION_ID - *int*
- USER_NAME_A - *nvarchar(20)*

**Permissions**

- PERMISSION_ID - *int*
- PERMISSION_NAME_A - *nvarchar(20)*

I'm using VS2012 .Net Framework 4.5... 
So could anyone help me?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question more so that others can help you better. What actually you are trying to do.

Comment: @HarishBhatt I tried to be more specific. English is not my best skill :)

Comment: i have posted my answer as per my understanding below, let me know is it working for you.

Comment: you need to get the reference of DropdownList in order to select value by below method, for this you can use below code:

`DropdownList ddList = (DropdownList)DetailsView2.Rows[i].FindControl("ddlEditPermissions");`

now you can use DropdownList object to select to deselect value using below method.

Comment: @HarishBhatt Thx for your time... I try to be little bit more specific. I wanna use that DropDownList SelectedValue property as parametr for the ObjectDataSource UpdateMethod.

Comment: I would suggest reading this: [Tutorial: Entity Data Source Control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/18/tutorial-entity-data-source-control.aspx). You will find an implementation [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18561613/690329).

Comment: I think you need to manipulate it in `onDataBound` event of DetailsView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... It was really simple. Thank you for your time ;)

I add the key into the keys in ItemUpdating event in DetailView.

```
protected void dtlvUserDetail_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList ddlEditPermissions= (DropDownList)dtlvUzivatel.FindControl("ddlEditPermissions");
            e.Keys["permission"] = ddlEditPermissions.SelectedValue;                
        }
```

Comment: For SelectedValue='<%# Bind("PermissionID") %>' did you call DataBind() for DropDownList?

Comment: There is a problem with `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("PermissionID") %>'`. It's not available in page design code as a DropDownList's property and I really don't know why. So I had to find a different way. And it is that simple.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can select DropdownList values:

```
if (ddlList.Items.FindByValue(<string type value you want to select from dropdownlist>) != null)
{
cboRegion.SelectedValue = ""; //Value you want to select if you are using Value attribute to select
}
```

Suppose you want to select vaulue "India" from drop down then it will be:

```
if (ddlList.Items.FindByValue("India") != null)
{
cboRegion.SelectedValue = "India";
}
```

or

```
string strValue = ddlList.Items.FindByValue("India").ToString();
if (strValue  != null)
{
cboRegion.SelectedValue = strValue ;
}
```

you can use `FindByValue` or `FindByText` methods to find values from DropdownList as below:

```
if (ddlList.Items.FindByText(<string type value you want to select from dropdownlist>) != null)
{
cboRegion.SelectedText = ""; //Value you want to select if you are using Value attribute to select
}
```