# DetailsView Object Binding with Property of type Dictionary

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to bind a detailsview to an object. The object contains a property of type Dictionary which I'm having an issue with getting that bound to a combo or listbox.
I'm trying to still use AutoGenerateRows, but maybe there's a magic attribute I can put on the property to make details view see it should draw a combo box for that property.

The object to bind:

```
Public Class Test
  Public Property MyTextboxProperty As String = "this works" 'binds fine
  Public Property MyComboBoxProperty As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"mykey", "myvalue"}} 'it just ignores this like it wasn't there
End Class
```

asp:

```
  <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="true" DefaultMode="Edit" DataKeyNames="">
    <Fields>

    </Fields>
  </asp:DetailsView>
```

Code Behind:

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      DetailsView1.DataSource = New List(Of Object) From {New Test}
      DetailsView1.DataBind()
  End Sub
```

It binds the string property fine. But it just ignores the dictionary property like it wasn't there. I can't find an example of what to add to make this work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using the DetailsView. I could not get it to work. I did a custom control that does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to display the drop down only when you allow the user to edit the DetailsView, this question may have what you are looking for, [ASP.Net - DropDownList used in EditItemTemplate in DetailsView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571149/asp-net-dropdownlist-used-in-edititemtemplate-in-detailsview).

Basically, you will need a template field where you define the state for the normal view and the editing view. Normal view would have the selected value displayed (new property below) and the editing view would have the list of values from your Dictionary bound to the drop down. You could also select the correct value in the drop down by selecting your selected value property.

To do this you need to create a new property for the selected value:

```
Public Class Test
  Public Property MyTextboxProperty As String = "this works" 'binds fine
  Public Property MyComboBoxSelectedProperty As String = "select me" 'this would be used to bind the normal view and select the value in the edit view
  Public Property MyComboBoxProperty As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"mykey", "myvalue"}} 'you can bind this to the datasource of the drop down
End Class
```

Comment: Luckily in this case there is no normal view. But there is no template in the asp code like in that question, because I don't know what the properties will be at runtime. Right now I'm working on adding the templates in the code behind. I was hoping I could coax reflection into getting it to just work without having to build the detailview's fields.